# ...the losers, frightened by the Juche missiles

Tags: phrase-meaning

Who are "frightened by the Juche missiles"? The losers or the US and the S.Korea?

> The furious piece said: “The US and the South Korean puppet military gangsters cry for miserable scream and piteous moan of **the losers, frightened by the Juche missiles** of the DPRK.

“If the US continues challenging the just cause of the DPRK in disregard of the strong might and will of Juche Korea, it can never escape the merciless strike of the powerful revolutionary Paektusan army.

Source: [Express (UK)](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/821621/north-korea-video-soldier-army-beating-defector)

Comment: The Express article links back to [an earlier Express article](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/820438/north-korea-war-ww3-usa-kim-jong-un), which does not, unfortunately, link to the source. Searching the phrase in question leads to [this WordReference thread](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/frightened-by-the-juche-missiles.3692293/) which, to my eye, you started a month ago. What reason do you have to ask the question again?

Comment: The quote is from North Korea, and is incorrect English.  Presumably the US and South Korea are the "losers" who are "frightened"  But I don't think there is much to be gained by doing grammatical analysts of this. vtc

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about non-idiomatic English the analysis of which would be of little use to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The US and the South Korean puppet military gangsters **cry for miserable scream** and piteous moan of the losers, frightened by the Juche missiles of the DPRK.

This sentence does not make sense grammatically. First of all, of course, "screams" and "moans" should be pluralized. But more importantly, I would expect either:

> 1. The US and SK gangsters **cry for *the* screams** of the losers
> 2. The US and SK gangsters **cry *the* screams** of the losers

The first option means that the American and South Korean gangsters want to hear the screams of the losers, who would (by process of elimination) be the North Koreans. This doesn't make sense in context, so probably the second option was intended: the Americans and South Koreans will cry the same screams that losers also cry.

In either case, it is syntactically ambiguous whether the clause "frightened by the Juche missiles" refers to *the gangsters* or *the losers*.